# How to configure codeship build for Cucumber Maven project . Like in Jenkins we can do it creating a Maven Project and then configuring our build

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, codeship

[CodeShip_Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx9pd.png)How to configure codeship build for Cucumber Maven project . Like in Jenkins we can do it creating a Maven Project and then configuring our build to include POM and Extent reports etc. How can we achieve this in codeship?

Comment: can somebody help me in this? its quite urgent for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the way to configure the Build for Java Maven Cucumber testing framework in Codeship. However, now I got stuck at one point. Where it seems some configurable problem related to ChromeDriver.

I want to use Chrome Browser and I am not sure what’s the path to ChromeDriver.exe. However, I tried with what I can get from the blog post( https://blog.codeship.com/cucumber-continuous-integration/ ) . 
.
I suppose the path to chromedriver is  “/user/din/google-chrome”   **** Please refer attached image for my CodeShip configuration and error while running the build**